# Browsermob standalone server : Not able to capture HAR : Mobile

Tags: browsermob, browsermob-proxy

I am trying to capture HAR using browsermob standalone server. But, once the server is started and server:port is configured in mobile i am not able to connect to internet. Below is the steps i have followed.

1. Download browsermob from below location : https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/releases/download/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4-bin.zip
2. ./browsermob-proxy -port 9090
   `[INFO  2017-03-29T14:08:38,256 org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer] (qtp1375394559-17) Proxy started at address: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8081`
3. curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/proxy
   `{"port":8081}`
4. curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/proxy
   `From the above INFO log i got server as 0.0.0.0 and port is 8081.`

   i configured below in mobile (iPhone 6plus, OS 10.3): 
   `HTTP Proxy > Manual
   server : 0.0.0.0, port:8081`

   After doing the above proxy changes, i am not able to connect to internet in mobile.
5. curl -X get http://localhost:9090/proxy

Here i get HAR with empty entries.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Please try to change the proxy of your device to match the IP address of the device your are running your browsermob proxy.

2.If you give 0.0.0.0 the browsermob cannot POST network into device. basically browsermob intercepts traffic going and coming through the ip address in which your standalone proxy is running

3.So make sure your device WiFi manual proxy is also same as your device ip address to access network.

Comment: With the above change i am now able to access contents from mobile browser. But mobile apps are not able to connect to internet. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you specify platform you are working on. Android or IOS?

Comment: Andriod seems to be working fine. There are issues with IOS though.

Comment: Did you install SSL certificates in your device??